# Sorting an object with php (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have an object which contains photo file paths,there caption and the order they apear in etc.

I need to sort the individual photos in order of the 'order', So that when i loop through each of the photos, they appear in the order specified by the order value.

Here is an example object:

```
    object: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Photo Object
                (
                    [timestamps] => 
                    [guarded:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => id
                        )

                    [connection:protected] => 
                    [table:protected] => 
                    [primaryKey:protected] => id
                    [perPage:protected] => 15
                    [incrementing] => 1
                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 11
                            [res_id] => 1
                            [order] => 6
                            [owner_type] => Hotel
                            [owner_id] => 1
                            [gallery] => 
                            [caption] => 
                            [file] => Hotel_1_11.jpg
                            [deleted_at] => 
                        )
```

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent  search for `orderBy`

Comment: The issue is I can't query the database - I have to just manipulate the object printed above

Comment: Read the docs.  It's not an issue.

Comment: In Laravel you can easily get them in order, with existing functions.

Comment: I found this $users = DB::table('users')->orderBy('name', 'desc')->get(); However this queries the database which I cant do. is there a way around?. I'm basically after what asort does to an array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's always better to sort data in the database, like that:

```
$photos = Photo::orderBy('order')->get();
```

This should give you better performance.

However, if above is not possible, you can call the following on your collection:

```
$collection = $collection->sortBy('order');
```

This will sort it in ascending order by the **order** field of whatever models you have there.

In case you want to sort them in descending order, do:

```
$collection = $collection->sortBy('order', SORT_REGULAR, true);
```

Comment: Thanks bro. it saved my life tonight

Answer (score 2):

Since Laravel 5.1 you can use a rather shorter syntax to order in **descending** order:

```
$collection = $collection->sortByDesc('order');
```

Instead of:

```
$collection = $collection->sortBy('order', SORT_REGULAR, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a collection, and you want to sort it on basis of any of it's key, then you can use the following piece of code.

```
//if you want to sort in ascending order
$unique     = $collection->unique()->sortBy('YOUR_KEY_TO_SORT');

//if you want to sort in descending order
$unique     = $collection->unique()->sortBy('YOUR_KEY_TO_SORT',  SORT_REGULAR,  true);
```